# Why doesn't css3 animation not working properly in React?

Tags: reactjs

In React i have a lifecycle method called componentDidMount. Inside that method i'm calling a function called change. Function change has a setState that changes the property classAnimation value from '' to 'testing2 animate'.
In my animations.js file i have component called home and inside that component i have assigned className with a property value called props.testing.

For some reason the text that is inside component should move from left to right when i apply the .testing2 and .animate classes, but it doesn't.

Help would be nice.

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Animations from './components/animations';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      classAnimation: '' 
    };

}


change = () => {
    this.setState({
      classAnimation: 'testing2 animate'
    });
}




componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.myFunction)
    this.change()
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.myFunction)
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Animations testing={this.state.classAnimation}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**ANIMATIONS.JS**

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = (props) => {

return(
    <div>
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="curriculum">
                <div className={props.testing}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
           </div>     

        </div>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

**APP.CSS**

```
body{
  height:1500px;
}


.curriculum{
    max-width:700px;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:2px solid black; 
}

/*---------- animation -----------------*/


@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to {opacity: 1;} }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to {opacity: 1;} }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to {opacity: 1;} }


.animate {

    -webkit-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;

    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;


    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -animation-duration: 1s;

}

.testing2.animate{
    color:red;
    -webkit-transform: translate(3em,0);
    -moz-transform: translate(3em,0);
    transform: translate(3em,0);
 }
```

**THIS IS WHAT I GET:**
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit text that changes color to red and has fade in animation.

**THIS IS WHAT I WANT:**
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit text that changes color to red and has fade in animation **AND** moves left to right.